# Facebook and Whatsapp sharing buttons

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have an PHP page showing an image to the user, and I want them to share via Facebook or WhatsApp, 
Here the code for the head part:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $Rowdati['metadescrizione'];?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $Rowdati['keywordsapp'];?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $urlimmagineuser; ?>">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $Rowdati['titolo_fb_share'];?>">
<meta property="og:description " content="<?php echo $Rowdati['descr_fb_share'];?>">
```

Here the code for getting the image to share and display on the web page:

```
<?php echo "<a href='". $url ."' download='image-ready'>
    <img id='immaginelaborata' class='img-responsive' src='". $url ."' />
    </a>";
?>
```

Here the share buttons:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" data-href="<?php echo $actual_link;?>" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
    <button class="btn col-xs-12 scroll_effect shadow-top-down">
        <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $actual_link;?>;src=sdkpreparse">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>share on FB</a>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button class="btn col-xs-12 scroll_effect shadow-top-down">
        <?php 
            $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") .         
            "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        ?>
        <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $Rowdati['testo_whatsapp'] . "http://mydomain.it";?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
            <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true" ></i><br>share on Whatsapp<br>
        </a>
    </button>
</div>
```

The page works fine, except that when i share it on Facebook or WhatsApp it does not return the image preview... 
I cannot figure out why after checking and rechecking the code.

Comment: Have you checked for errors via FB debug tool already?

Comment: Nope, thanks for the suggestion, now it is ok